# Opening certmgr.msc to display the Machine level certificates

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6, ssl-certificate, certificate

I want to view the certificates installed at the machine level, if I open certmgr.msc.

- I am aware that we can open an mmc and app a snap in for certmgr. But I dont want to go that way.
- I am aware that we can use the certmgr.exe with the -s and -r switches to achive the same. But I dont want to do that.

What I want is, Start| Run| certmgr.msc (with some command line options - if there are any) to view the machine level certificates. Currently that is defaulted to Current User.

On IIS 7/Win 2K8, when I import a certificate, it gets added to the HKLM. I am expecting a similar functionality with the certmgr.msc console.

If I open certmgr.msc, instead of opening the current user certificates, I want to open the machine level certificates. And when I import a certificate to the Trusted Root, I want it to be added at the Machine Level and not just the User Level.

It kind of bugs to go to mmc and add a snapin. If I had a (IIS6/Win2K3) instead of an (IIS 7/Win 2K8) - how would I go about adding the certitifcate to the machine level stores instead of user level stores using certmgr.msc?

If the question sounds irrational, thats what I am trying to achieve.
Thoughts/Ideas appreciated.

***Edit on Oct 30 2015***
according to mil bauer's answer - if you are on a Win 8/Server 2012 R2, try certlm.msc to open Certificates - Local Computer.

Comment: Yeah, you worded that well, and this has been a nagging question for me as well.

Answer (score 4):

certlm.msc will open the local machine store.

Comment: This doesn't work on Windows Server 2003 for me (which is the version tagged in the question). What version of Windows are you seeing this work for, out of curiosity?

Comment: Windows 8/Server 2012 R2

Comment: Thank you the command. Didn't know. I just tried certlm.msc on a Windows 8 machine and it opens Certificates - Local Computer. Wow, that's cool.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the snap-in to the a "blank" `MMC` instance is the only way I'm aware of to open the machine's certificate store in the management console. You can always save that console, if you'd like, so that you don't have to manually add the snap-in in the future, but the default `certmgr.msc` saved console has the Certificates snap-in targeted at the user.

Comment: Thx for the answer. Yes we can save the mmc console with a the certmgr snapin. "certmgr.msc saved console has the Certificates snap-in targeted at the user" - is sad :(